# Multiple compose files communicating

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 3 docker-compose files for different projects.

The first one is MySQL database, the second is my app and the third is another app that I made.

How can I specify in my app compose to use the database from MySQL compose?

I could've put all of them into 1 compose file, but when I change versions, I would need to use docker-compose down command and that would mean that MySQL would be unavailable as well, which I cannot afford to have, I need it up and running 24/7 without interruption since it's in production.

In my app config file, I specified MySQL connection to use container name/db and correct username and pass.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Docker-compose allow you to execute commands on a single service only. For example, `docker-compose stop app` would shutdown only the service `app` in the docker-compose. Otherwise, if you've got multiple independent docker-compose files, you have to map each needed container port to the host, and then define the communication channel through the host. But, of course, you lose an isolation level, by exposing your container port on the host. I always prefer using a single docker-compose config, and adapt my commands to my need.

Comment: Does it work to specify the stable production database host's DNS name (even if it's the same physical host)?  Since as you note the database and application have very different life cycles, it could make sense to ignore the implementation detail that the database is in a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change DB versions, you will always have to take the container down, or look to other means to perform an ETL with a new db and then make a switch through DNS.

If you mean 'when the app changes version', the DB will be restarted, then I believe you might be wrong.

Using `docker-compose up` will recreate your app container with a new image, and leave the other DB container unchanged if the config has not changed.

However, to answer your original question, you can allow containers to speak to each other by assigning them to the same Docker network, a [user assigned bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-driver-summary) would suit your needs well:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

I would recommend creating a network external to the `docker-compose` file, and then using it for your database and app. You can then use the relevant container name to connect to the database

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: Thank you so much, I was only missing the external parameter in my compose file.